# Odoo v8 fails to load from remote server installation

Tags: odoo

I downloaded latest version of Odoo (Openerp v8) from GitHub. When installed on my localhost (my pc) it works fine. Now whenever I tried to install it on my remote server, database is created but not loaded and I have a blank page when it comes to *my-remote-ip:8072/web* (I launched it `openerp-gevent` along my config file but the same happens with the `openerp-server` command too).

When I check the log file, the process is stuck at:

> .... INFO my-db-username openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_http: Generating
>   routing map

The last request processed by the system is:

> 'werkzeug.request': http://my-remote-ip:8072/web/js/web.assets_backend/77f77e2' [GET]>

This request is not served and leads to a blank page. I'm on ubuntu 14.04. 
I wonder if there is protection in the coding that prevents odoo to be used from a remote server.

Please, can someone help me how to bypass this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been testing in virtual machines recently. IMHO check the postgress database and if all is working fine, then check python dependences, perhaps you missed some?

I've used this quick guide with success for my ubuntu 14.04 Vm with [odoo 8](http://www.schenkels.nl/2014/07/install-odoo-v8-0-from-github-ubuntu-14-04-lts-formerly-openerp/)

Comment: The guide you've linked to may contain an answer to the question, but you should summarize the linked content in case the destination changes or becomes unreachable.

Comment: page not available anymore

Answer (score 2):

Use different DB for your remote server not same as localhost.

try to run remote server using this command

> > ./openerp-server --xmlrpc-port=8072

you can change the port number.

Hope this will help... :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but your answer is not satisfying. I said that it works well on a local installation. And I know quite well about the installation process whatsoever.
Now, try to install Odoo on a remote server using your IP adress (which is my case as I haven't given a domain name to my VPS yet). You will notice that the installation process is not going to its end and points to a blank screen. I need to have feedbacks from persons who have tried the same operation. Again, thanks for all your valuable contributions to this issue.